# SpringBoot application without a rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i´m new to spring and i´m currently working on a spring application to migrate data between 2 databases.

My question is, how is it going to run?? I mean, using spring, how to let spring knows where the migration process will start?

For example, assuming that i have 3 tables (Customer, Product and Invoices).

I´ll work on the classes to migrate first all data from customer, then product and finally invoices.

I´m confused on how spring will manage this when it starts.

Tks in advance.

Comment: Unclear question and no need for spring app for simple dB migration but JDBC allows for any custom logic implementation

Comment: You might be looking for a CommandLineRunner. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

Comment: @JAsgarov i understand that spring might not be needed, but what i´m trying to understand is if there´s no rest endpoint, how will this be managed by spring? Or it´s just simply that the endpoint IS required.

Comment: @Marged that looks like what i want to do. Or at least how it´s supposed to work with spring in a case like this. Tks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Marged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354537/marged) suggested, A `CommandLineRunner` application would just achieve what you're looking for:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourMigrationApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Application starts
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
        // Migration finished
    }
 
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        // Migrate Customer data
        // Migrate Product data
        // Migrate Invoice data
    }
}
```

When the migrate invoice data step completes, your application will exit since there's nothing left to run. (And you don't have any controllers etc. to continue listen to).

Comment: Sure. If this was any help to you and resolved your issue, maybe you could accept the answer?